# Creating slanted edges for 50% columns with an image behind

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRfbF.png)

[image]

I figure this would be possible by skewing an :after pseudo or maybe with a lot of work with borders, but it's having the content on top, and the image behind that I'm really struggling with, any ideas at all are welcome. Or if it's just too much of a nightmare to be possible,

I know there are a lot of questions about slanted edges, but none were the same scenario as this.

Comment: The reason SO is such a good recourse is not because of question like this. We don't provide the code for you - You show us the code and the issue you're having with it. Visit help center to learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[my solution](http://codepen.io/matthsiung/pen/JKOYkk)

```
Figuring out how to get it responsive is up to you =)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would consider is how these elements will stack on each other, and how they will be shown on small displays. From your image it seems each one contains 4 elements like `<h1> <p> <button>` and `<img>` what is unclear is if you would like to push the `<img>` under the others or to the right of them. I suggest in any case placing them in and order that is understandable without CSS making them consistent and understandable for small displays and assigning the appropriate background color to each. Then once you have the real estate to move them side by side float them left or right (depending on where you want them) Then apply a simple background image for your divider in the appropriate container. The simplest HTML code example I could come up with base on what you have shown me is this:

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <img src="drinks-image.jpg" alt="drinks image">
    </figure>
    <div>
      <h1>Drinks</h1>
      <p>drinks text goes here</p>
      <button>button</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <img src="bookig-image.jpg" alt="booking image">
    </figure>
    <div>
      <h1>Book Your Seat</h1>
      <p>booking text goes here</p>
      <button>button</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

I hope this helps you, or at least gets you started.  I wish I could give you more information but I don't have much to go on.  There are several ways your could do this that would be compatible with many versions of browsers. In any case you would want to utilize background colors and add a background image only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS below will give you a slanted edge; tested with Chrome, Firefox and IE11.

```css
.slanted-edge {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border: 50px solid grey;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

To create a slanted edge, you take a 0-sized shape and add a border that is half the size of the height of the edge you want - in this example, I wanted a shape that's 100px high, so I used 50px.

You have to then visualise two diagonal lines connecting opposite corners, approximately like [x], which divides the image into four triangles. You can set each of those triangles to be transparent by setting the border-color attribute of that side to be transparent.

To realise the look you're looking for, you'll probably need four columns, the two in the middle being the slanted edges, and the content & the image being the two on the outer columns. Of course, you can use `::after` and `::before` on the content and the image to create the slanted edges, but I haven't tested it.